# Start Ubuntu from SDHC card without booting into it

Tags: boot, startup

I have a SDHC card from which I can not boot, ecause the internal SDHC reader of my Lenovo laptop isn't recognize it.
I can boot from it on my other Notebook without any problems.
Nevertheless I can mount and access the SDHC card from the first notebook.

Is it in any way possible to start the SDHC Ubuntu OS on the first notebook after booting into its main Ubuntu OS?

Comment: Can it boot if you use a SD adaptor?

Comment: I tried it. No. I also tried to use the working SDHC card in an external card reader via USB. Also not recognized in the boot menu at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is impossible. If you boot from your internal HD, you can't boot from your SDHC card.. because you are booting from your HD and not from your SDHC card.
And to answer to your question, what your are asking is impossible. Your notebook to startup have to know where point what, if you don't declare (choose what to boot) where to start your PC won't start because it hasn't a starting point (boot drive).
All right?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought to startup the SDHC card OS more like I switch via 'change root' into another OS or something.

Comment: Isn't it possible for an already started Ubuntu OS to use a mounted source to replace the running kernel and everything with a new OS without reboot?

Comment: No, technically is impossible (as far as I know). To solve your problem you should put your SDHC card to a usb card reader and boot from that drive.

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't work. I tried to use the working SDHC card in an external card reader via USB. Also not recognized in the boot menu at startup.

Comment: I think that there is something that doesn't works well. If you have not to save changes you can run Ubuntu from a Live CD, and save your files (documents, photo, whatever you want...) in the SDHC card.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no CD/DVD device

Comment: You should try a different SDHC card, or with a pen-drive that your notebook recognizes.